# How to output xml characters with disable-output-escaping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am using xslt to transform an xml document. I need to use output escaping to get my result because the work server I am using will only output a closing tag of `<site/>` no matter what I try to do. I found this statement which confirms my problem.

"XSLT outputs a result tree, it doesn't output tags (unless you use the disable-output-escaping hack). It's the serializer that takes the result tree and produces appropriate tags. If you're generating XML, use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`. The serializer will decide whether to use `<textarea></textarea>` or `<textarea/>`. In XML, both forms are completely equivalent, so any consumer of the XML will accept either."

I want my resulting document to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sites>
   <site>
      <pole>
            NAM
        </pole>
      <territory>
            Northeast
        </territory>
      <position>
            FSR
        </position>
      <platform>
            Mobile
        </platform>
      <latitude>
            -76.631056373393
        </latitude>
      <longitude>
            36.98237439172
        </longitude>
      <firstName>
            Justin
        </firstName>
      <lastName>
            Rhodes
        </lastName>
   </site>
   <site>
      <pole>
            NAM
        </pole>
      <territory>
            Northeast
        </territory>
      <position>
            FSR
        </position>
      <platform>
            Mobile
        </platform>
      <latitude>
            -71.454786492200
        </latitude>
      <longitude>
            42.995647573539
        </longitude>
      <firstName>
            Kevin
        </firstName>
      <lastName>
            Woods
        </lastName>
   </site>
</sites>
```

I am using the following xslt document:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- New document created with EditiX at Mon Jun 03 12:57:03 EDT 2013 -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method = "xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <sites>
        <xsl:for-each select="/ViewAll/ROW">

            <site>
                <pole>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_1/text()"/>
                </pole>
                <territory>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_2/text()"/>
                </territory>
                <position>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_3/text()"/>
                </position>
                <platform>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_4/text()"/>
                </platform>
                <latitude>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_5/text()"/>
                </latitude>
                <longitude>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_6/text()"/>
                </longitude>
                <firstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_8/text()"/>
                </firstName>
                <lastName>
            <xsl:value-of select="SC_DF_FIELD_9/text()"/>
                </lastName>
            </site>

        </xsl:for-each>
        </sites>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>
    <!--This causes everything else in the document output to be ignored -->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am applying the xslt to this xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myFirstTemplate4.xsl"?>
    <ViewAll>
    <RECORDSET_METADATA>
        <STARTREC>1</STARTREC>
        <KEYFIELDS>False</KEYFIELDS>
        <ENDREC>2</ENDREC>
        <TOTALREC>2</TOTALREC>
        <PAme_NO>1</PAme_NO>
        <SORT_TYPE>DT_UPDATED</SORT_TYPE>
        <SORT_ORDER>desc</SORT_ORDER>
        <FORM_ID>427384</FORM_ID>
        <REPORT_ID></REPORT_ID>
        <SAVED_ID></SAVED_ID>
        <NEXTSORTORDER>
            <![CDATA[&sortorder=desc]]>
        </NEXTSORTORDER>
        <SC_DF_XSL_HELP_URL>
            <![CDATA[http://libraries.me.com/LibrariesWiki/2767051101/Data%20Forms%20- %20Customizing%20Records%20View]]>
        </SC_DF_XSL_HELP_URL>
        <FILTER_DATA>
            <![CDATA[var AdvSrchFltrXML_String =  { AdvSrchFltrData  : { filter : [ {selElementType  : '',selElementParentDF  : '',selComb  : '',exclCheck  : '',selElement  : '',query  : '',query_psrch  : '',includeNull  : '',lockFilter  : '',lockFilterFlg  : '',dateFrom  : '',dateTo  : '',betweenDaysFrom  : '',betweenDaysTo  : '',betweenDaysFromOption  : '',betweenDaysToOption  : '',exactDaysOption  : '',exactDays  : '',moreThanOption  : '',moreThan  : '',NumAgingQuery  : '',betweenNumFrom  : '',betweenNumTo  : '',GreaterOrLessOrEqualToNum  : '',dateFromFormat  : '',dateToFormat  : ''} ] },size : 1, HiddenXMLFilterCount :''}]]>
        </FILTER_DATA>
        <FILTER_FIELDS>
            <![CDATA[ var arrFields = new Array(new Array("form_doc_id","Entry #","req","","","","",""),new Array("LOGmeD_BY","Logmed By","psrch","","","","","1"),new Array("DT_LOGmeD","Date Logmed","dt","","","","",""),new Array("LAST_UPDATED_BY","Last Updated By","psrch","","","","","1"),new Array("DT_UPDATED","Date Updated","dt","","","","",""))]]>
        </FILTER_FIELDS>
        <meNERATE_HIDDEN_VAR>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </meNERATE_HIDDEN_VAR>
        <HIDDEN_XML_FILTER_COUNT>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </HIDDEN_XML_FILTER_COUNT>
        <HIDDEN_FILTER_REMOVE_NUMBER>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </HIDDEN_FILTER_REMOVE_NUMBER>
        <DF_LINK_FIELDS_VAR>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </DF_LINK_FIELDS_VAR>
        <SA_UPLOAD_FLAG>
            <![CDATA[-1]]>
        </SA_UPLOAD_FLAG>
        <FLG_EXPORT_PDF_WORD>0</FLG_EXPORT_PDF_WORD>
        <FLG_DISABLE_BULK_UPDATE_APPEND>0</FLG_DISABLE_BULK_UPDATE_APPEND>
        <FLG_EXPORT_KML>1</FLG_EXPORT_KML>
        <FLG_EXPORT_TO_MAP>0</FLG_EXPORT_TO_MAP>
        <PUBLISHED_FLAG>0</PUBLISHED_FLAG>
        <STR_CREATE_ORDER>402</STR_CREATE_ORDER>
        <FUNC_CREATE_ORDER>asc</FUNC_CREATE_ORDER>
        <FORM_NAME>Map Points</FORM_NAME>
        <PROD_ID>267672</PROD_ID>
        <ARCHIVE_FLAG>0</ARCHIVE_FLAG>
        <FACILITATOR_FLAG>1</FACILITATOR_FLAG>
        <ADVANCED_SEARCH_FLAG>1</ADVANCED_SEARCH_FLAG>
        <EXPORT_ALL_FLAG>1</EXPORT_ALL_FLAG>
        <EXPORT_PAme_FLAG>0</EXPORT_PAme_FLAG>
        <DELETE_RECORD_FLAG>1</DELETE_RECORD_FLAG>
        <FIELDCHOOSER_EDIT_FLAG>1</FIELDCHOOSER_EDIT_FLAG>
        <FIELDCHOOSER_COPY_FLAG>1</FIELDCHOOSER_COPY_FLAG>
        <RSS_FEED>1</RSS_FEED>
        <FIELD_CHOOSER_ENABLE_FLAG>1</FIELD_CHOOSER_ENABLE_FLAG>
        <ARCHIVE_ALL_ENABLE_FLAG>1</ARCHIVE_ALL_ENABLE_FLAG>
        <TRUNCATE_TEXT_FLAG>0</TRUNCATE_TEXT_FLAG>
        <CALLED_FOR></CALLED_FOR>
        <CALLING_ENTITY_TYPE></CALLING_ENTITY_TYPE>
        <EXCELUPLOADFLAG>true</EXCELUPLOADFLAG>
        <VIEWAUDITTRAIL>1</VIEWAUDITTRAIL>
        <STATICSERVER>//supportcentral.mecdn.com</STATICSERVER>
        <VIEWERS_DETAIL>
            <V_SSO_ID>218012021</V_SSO_ID>
            <V_PERSON_ID>1273277</V_PERSON_ID>
            <V_FIRST_NAME>meoffrey</V_FIRST_NAME>
            <V_LAST_NAME>melinas</V_LAST_NAME>
            <V_BUSINESS_SEGMENT>Power &amp; Water</V_BUSINESS_SEGMENT>
            <V_FOCUS_GROUP>me Power &amp; Water</V_FOCUS_GROUP>
            <V_SUB_BUSINESS>PW-WTR Water</V_SUB_BUSINESS>
            <V_LANGUAme>english</V_LANGUAme>
            <V_FUNCTION>Services</V_FUNCTION>
        </VIEWERS_DETAIL>
    </RECORDSET_METADATA>
    <DFLINK_ELEMENT_DETAILS>
        <CalledForSF display_name="CalledForSF" search_field="No">&amp;nbsp</CalledForSF>
        <SOURCE_ELEMENT_ID display_name="SOURCE_ELEMENT_ID" search_field="No">&amp;nbsp</SOURCE_ELEMENT_ID>
        <TARmeT_ELEMENT_ID display_name="TARmeT_ELEMENT_ID" search_field="No">&amp;nbsp</TARmeT_ELEMENT_ID>
    </DFLINK_ELEMENT_DETAILS>
    <DF_FIELDS>
        <SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID display_name="Entry #" search_field="Yes">Entry #</SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD display_name="Date Logmed" search_field="Yes">Logmed Date</SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED display_name="Date Updated" search_field="Yes">Last Updated Date</SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY display_name="Logmed By" search_field="Yes">Logmed by</SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY display_name="Last Updated By" search_field="Yes">Last Updated By</SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL_HEADER display_name="Audit Trail" search_field="Yes">Audit Trail</SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL_HEADER>
    </DF_FIELDS>
    <HEADER>
        <SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID display_name="Entry #" search_field="Yes">Entry #</SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD display_name="Date Logmed" search_field="Yes">Logmed Date</SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED display_name="Date Updated" search_field="Yes">Last Updated Date</SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY display_name="Logmed By" search_field="Yes">Logmed by</SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY display_name="Last Updated By" search_field="Yes">Last Updated By</SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL display_name="Audit Trail" search_field="Yes">Audit Trail</SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_1 display_name="Poll" element_type="d" el_values="NAM;LAM;APAC;EUR;MEA" search_field="No">Poll</SC_DF_FIELD_1>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_2 display_name="Territory" element_type="d" el_values="Northeast;Southeast;Midwest;West;Plains;Canada" search_field="No">Territory</SC_DF_FIELD_2>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_3 display_name="Position" element_type="d" el_values="FSR" search_field="No">Position</SC_DF_FIELD_3>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_4 display_name="Platform" element_type="d" el_values="BOO;Mobile;UF/MBR;Captial" search_field="No">Platform</SC_DF_FIELD_4>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_5 display_name="Longitude" element_type="t" search_field="No">Longitude</SC_DF_FIELD_5>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_6 display_name="Latitude" element_type="t" search_field="No">Latitude</SC_DF_FIELD_6>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_8 display_name="First Name" element_type="t" search_field="No">First Name</SC_DF_FIELD_8>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_9 display_name="Last Name" element_type="t" search_field="No">Last Name</SC_DF_FIELD_9>
    </HEADER>
    <ROW edit_access="1">
        <SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID_ACTION display_name="Entry # For Actions">
            <![CDATA[6526927427]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID_ACTION>
        <SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID display_name="Entry #">
            <![CDATA[6526927427]]>
            <ENTRY_VIEW_URL display_name="View Entry URL">
                <![CDATA[http://supportcentral.me.com/dataforms/sup_dataform_display.asp?dataform_id=427384&dataform_doc_id=6526927427]]>
            </ENTRY_VIEW_URL>
        </SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD display_name="Date Logmed">
            <![CDATA[6/3/2013 11:48:27 AM]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED display_name="Date Updated">
            <![CDATA[6/3/2013 11:48:27 AM]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY display_name="Logmed By">
            <![CDATA[&nbsp]]>
            <PERSON>
                <SC_DF_PERSON_LINK display_name="Profile Url">
                    <![CDATA[../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277]]>
                </SC_DF_PERSON_LINK>
                <SC_DF_SSO display_name="">
                    <![CDATA[218012021]]>
                </SC_DF_SSO>
                <SC_DF_EMAIL display_name="Email">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey.melinas@me.com]]>
                </SC_DF_EMAIL>
                <SC_DF_FIRST_NAME display_name="First Name">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey]]>
                </SC_DF_FIRST_NAME>
                <SC_DF_LAST_NAME display_name="Last Name">
                    <![CDATA[melinas]]>
                </SC_DF_LAST_NAME>
            </PERSON>
            <PERSON_STRING>
                <PERSON_STRING_VAR display_name="person person person">
                    <![CDATA[var person_String = {person : [ {PERSON_ID  : '../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277',FIRST_NAME  : 'meoffrey',LAST_NAME:'melinas'}], size : 1 }]]>
                </PERSON_STRING_VAR>
            </PERSON_STRING>
        </SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY display_name="Last Updated By">
            <![CDATA[&nbsp]]>
            <PERSON>
                <SC_DF_PERSON_LINK display_name="Profile Url">
                    <![CDATA[../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277]]>
                </SC_DF_PERSON_LINK>
                <SC_DF_SSO display_name="">
                    <![CDATA[218012021]]>
                </SC_DF_SSO>
                <SC_DF_EMAIL display_name="Email">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey.melinas@me.com]]>
                </SC_DF_EMAIL>
                <SC_DF_FIRST_NAME display_name="First Name">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey]]>
                </SC_DF_FIRST_NAME>
                <SC_DF_LAST_NAME display_name="Last Name">
                    <![CDATA[melinas]]>
                </SC_DF_LAST_NAME>
            </PERSON>
            <PERSON_STRING>
                <PERSON_STRING_VAR display_name="person person person">
                    <![CDATA[var person_String = {person : [ {PERSON_ID  : '../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277',FIRST_NAME  : 'meoffrey',LAST_NAME:'melinas'}], size : 1 }]]>
                </PERSON_STRING_VAR>
            </PERSON_STRING>
        </SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL display_name="Audit Trail">
            <![CDATA[<a href="../caseforms/complete_audit_trail.asp?calling_entity_id=427384&form_doc_id=6526927427&pameNo=0&auditType=0&callinmentity=4" tarmet="_none">Audit Trail</a>]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_1 display_name="Poll" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[NAM]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_1>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_2 display_name="Territory" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[Northeast]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_2>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_3 display_name="Position" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[FSR]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_3>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_4 display_name="Platform" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[Mobile]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_4>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_5 display_name="Longitude" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[-76.631056373393]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_5>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_6 display_name="Latitude" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[36.98237439172]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_6>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_8 display_name="First Name" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[Justin]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_8>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_9 display_name="Last Name" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[Rhodes]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_9>
    </ROW>
    <ROW edit_access="1">
        <SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID_ACTION display_name="Entry # For Actions">
            <![CDATA[6526927192]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID_ACTION>
        <SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID display_name="Entry #">
            <![CDATA[6526927192]]>
            <ENTRY_VIEW_URL display_name="View Entry URL">
                <![CDATA[http://supportcentral.me.com/dataforms/sup_dataform_display.asp?dataform_id=427384&dataform_doc_id=6526927192]]>
            </ENTRY_VIEW_URL>
        </SC_SYS_DF_FORM_DOC_ID>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD display_name="Date Logmed">
            <![CDATA[6/3/2013 11:47:41 AM]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_DT_LOGmeD>
        <SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED display_name="Date Updated">
            <![CDATA[6/3/2013 11:47:41 AM]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_DT_UPDATED>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY display_name="Logged By">
            <![CDATA[&nbsp]]>
            <PERSON>
                <SC_DF_PERSON_LINK display_name="Profile Url">
                    <![CDATA[../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277]]>
                </SC_DF_PERSON_LINK>
                <SC_DF_SSO display_name="">
                    <![CDATA[218012021]]>
                </SC_DF_SSO>
                <SC_DF_EMAIL display_name="Email">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey.melinas@me.com]]>
                </SC_DF_EMAIL>
                <SC_DF_FIRST_NAME display_name="First Name">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey]]>
                </SC_DF_FIRST_NAME>
                <SC_DF_LAST_NAME display_name="Last Name">
                    <![CDATA[melinas]]>
                </SC_DF_LAST_NAME>
            </PERSON>
            <PERSON_STRING>
         <PERSON_STRING_VAR display_name="person person person">
         <![CDATA[var person_String = {person : [ {PERSON_ID  : '../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277',FIRST_NAME  : 'meoffrey',LAST_NAME:'melinas'}], size : 1 }]]>
                </PERSON_STRING_VAR>
            </PERSON_STRING>
        </SC_SYS_DF_LOGmeD_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY display_name="Last Updated By">
            <![CDATA[&nbsp]]>
            <PERSON>
                <SC_DF_PERSON_LINK display_name="Profile Url">
                    <![CDATA[../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277]]>
                </SC_DF_PERSON_LINK>
                <SC_DF_SSO display_name="">
                    <![CDATA[218012021]]>
                </SC_DF_SSO>
                <SC_DF_EMAIL display_name="Email">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey.melinas@me.com]]>
                </SC_DF_EMAIL>
                <SC_DF_FIRST_NAME display_name="First Name">
                    <![CDATA[meoffrey]]>
                </SC_DF_FIRST_NAME>
                <SC_DF_LAST_NAME display_name="Last Name">
                    <![CDATA[melinas]]>
                </SC_DF_LAST_NAME>
            </PERSON>
            <PERSON_STRING>
                <PERSON_STRING_VAR display_name="person person person">
                    <![CDATA[var person_String = {person : [ {PERSON_ID  : '../common/sup_persondtls.asp?p_id=1273277',FIRST_NAME  : 'meoffrey',LAST_NAME:'melinas'}], size : 1 }]]>
                </PERSON_STRING_VAR>
            </PERSON_STRING>
        </SC_SYS_DF_LAST_UPDATED_BY>
        <SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL display_name="Audit Trail">
            <![CDATA[<a href="../caseforms/complete_audit_trail.asp?calling_entity_id=427384&form_doc_id=6526927192&pameNo=0&auditType=0&callinmentity=4" tarmet="_none">Audit Trail</a>]]>
        </SC_SYS_DF_AUDIT_TRAIL>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_1 display_name="Poll" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[NAM]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_1>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_2 display_name="Territory" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[Northeast]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_2>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_3 display_name="Position" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[FSR]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_3>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_4 display_name="Platform" element_type="d">
            <![CDATA[Mobile]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_4>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_5 display_name="Longitude" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[-71.454786492200]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_5>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_6 display_name="Latitude" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[42.995647573539]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_6>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_8 display_name="First Name" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[Kevin]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_8>
        <SC_DF_FIELD_9 display_name="Last Name" element_type="t" data_type="alpha">
            <![CDATA[Woods]]>
        </SC_DF_FIELD_9>
    </ROW>
    </ViewAll>
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the result im looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your supplied XSLT code, when run using Saxon, produces (as far as I can tell) exactly the output you are looking for. How does your output differ, and how are you obtaining it?

You certainly don't seem to have any need for disable-output-escaping.

Your question in any case is very confused. You say you get "a closing tag of `<site/>` no matter what you do", but (a) `<site/>` is not a closing tag, it is an empty-element tag, and (b) you don't explain why you don't want a closing tag. You say you want output escaping, which is the normal default, so why are you interested in disable output escaping, which switches it off?

Comment: I know this code works just fine when applying to my local server and when I run it through an xslt test, it comes back as valid. However, when this code is put up on my WORK server the result I get back is just a closing tag of <site/>. If you read the second paragraph from the top it states that on some servers the serializer decides what the output will be and that only returning this tag is legitimate. It is for this reason that I need to use escaping so that I can force the server to produce the output that I am asking for, the same code that I showed in the first set shown above.

Comment: I need to force the server to give me the output which from my understanding can be done with escaping, is this true?

Comment: Oh dear, you are very confused, it's hard to know where to start. If you are getting back an empty `<site/>` element, that is nothing to do with serialization or escaping. It means the transformation is producing the wrong answer, and to find out why, we need to look in a different place from where you are looking. My guess from the evidence is that you are running your XSLT against a different input file from the one shown: one where `/ViewAll/ROW` selects nothing.

Comment: Did you read the second paragraph above? This is the only explanation I come up with as to why I get perfect results back from my local server but only get a <site/> tag back from the work server. Your guess is incorrect. I have tried this multiple times in many places and its only the work server giving me this problem. It has to do with this particular server.

Comment: The second paragraph you quoted is totally irrelevant to the problem. It does not give the serializer license to replace a `<site>` element with content by an empty `<site/>` element. You're obsessively chasing a red herring and ignoring advice to look elsewhere.

Comment: Mr. Kay...Perhaps you are correct, but I must say your manner of speaking is very condescending and unprofessional. "Im very confused", "obsessively chasing a red heron"??? Im going to start my post over. Please dont comment on my question and I promise I wont buy any of your books. P.S. this is my first time using xslt. Why dont you come over to Java so I can talk down at you.

Comment: Sorry if my frustration came through. It's frustrating when you try to help people and they won't take your advice.